# Соединение с БД

Tags: php

При попытке соединения с БД выскакивает ошибка Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given. В функции выбора БД сначала указ. подключение, и затем имя БД (если не ошибаюсь, так и должно быть)

```
 <?

    function connect() {

        $db_host = "localhost";             // Сервер
        $db_user = "root";          // Имя пользователя
        $db_password = "";  // Пароль пользователя
        $db_name = "yii";               // Имя базы данных

        // Подключаемся к серверу
        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die("<p>1 Невозможно подключиться к СУБД</p>");
        $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name) or die("<p>2 Невозможно подключиться к базе данных</p>");
        $query = mysqli_query("set names utf8", $conn) or die("<p>3 Невозможно выполнить запрос к базе данных</p>");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password)` прописать `$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysqli_query("set names utf8", $conn) or die("<p>3 Невозможно выполнить запрос к базе данных</p>");
```

заменить на

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "set names utf8") or die("<p>3 Невозможно выполнить запрос к базе данных</p>");
```